# javascript import/require Error: Cannot find module '@react-select/monorepo' from '.../src/static/js/react_apps/utils'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browserify, react-select

I'm having issues importing a module not via NPM:

I forked the repo and also tried a local install with no luck, so I tried installing via github.

I've tried both using import as well as require as listed below. Not quite sure why it keeps insisting to look in locally

The file that's having issue is in the `utils` folder, which is probably why it's searching for react-select there.

```
import Select from "@react-select/monorepo";
const Select = require("@react-select/monorepo");
```

What does work (when installed via npm repository):

```
import Select from "react-select";
```

Package.json:

```
    "@react-select/monorepo": "github:kckaiwei/react-select#onMultiValueLabelClick",
```

Getting the following error when running `browserify`:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@react-select/monorepo' from '.../src/static/js/react_apps/utils'
    at .../node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (.../node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (.../node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (.../node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (.../node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at .../node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
```

Directory structure looks like:

```
project --- src --- static
       |
       |--- node_modules --- @react-select --- monorepo
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but since you said

> I'm having issues importing a module not via NPM:
>
> I forked the repo

I can argue you want to import in your project a locally changed version of `react-select`.

If that's actually what you want to do, you are looking for [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

1. git checkout forked_repos
2. cd forked_repos_directory
3. npm link
4. cd your_project_directory
5. npm link react-select

That's all, you neither need to change the import statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `.../PycharmProjects/project/node_modules/react-select-new -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-select-new -> .../PycharmProjects/react-select`

Is what I get after doing npm link react-select, which seems to show they bind properly. However, running browserify afterwards still gives the same error. I think there's something with Browserify not reading the local node_modules?

Comment: That's out of my knowledge; as you did "dirty things" in your `node_modules` directory, it could be a good idea to remove it and run again both `npm link react-select` and `npm install`. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm still a bit new to node_modules, what do you mean by dirty things, just messing around with it? I'll try that.

Comment: You touched it. `nome_modules` is a black box, just let `npm` to change it and forget about it. By the way, if you cloned the forked repos inside `node_modules`, clone it somewhere else and repeat the entire procedure.

Comment: Got it, I deleted node_modules, and ran the link then install with no luck. The repo was cloned outside of node_modules, at the same level as the project. I think it's a browserify (since it uses browser-resolve) issue at this point. I tried following tutorials on building a new module from scratch, and it doesn't look like I've deviated from the path, since they suggest npm link as well.

Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution to this, but after much deliberating, I ended up just installing via NPM by creating a separate package for my branch, which does work but requires maintaining this branch, which was going to be necessary anyways due to forking.